# Child components not updating in Safari. Works like a charm in Chrome and FF

Tags: reactjs, safari

My app has a loading state while using fetch to retrieve data from an API.

I'm using a callback to `setState` to toggle between `loading: true` and `loading: false`. Everything works perfectly in FF and Chrome but chokes and dies in Safari.

With `react-devtools` I can see that I'm receiving data from the API. My state.loading is even updated to false.

However, the child components are not being updated and I'm stuck with an eternal spinner.

The Safari console is completely blank.

If I pull the loading state out of the app everything loads. But then I get a `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'openingComment.nextSibling')` on every click event. Not getting that in Chrome and FF either.

I'm at a loss here. How do I exorcise these Safari demons? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the relevant code. I'm pre-refactor stage so I know a lot of this can be improved. i.e. calling setState twice in the same function etc.

from App.js

```
    class App extends Component {

      state = {
        data: {},
        formData: {},
        loading: true
      }

      getFormData = () => {
        const newState = {
          // Getting formData from url params
        }

        const mergedState = {...this.state, ...newState}

        this.setState(mergedState, () => {
          // get data from API
          getData(this.state.formData, (data) => {

            let newState = {
              data,
              loading: false
            }

            const mergedState = {...this.state, ...newState}

            this.setState(mergedState)
          })
        })
      }

      setFormData = (formData) => {

        const parsedAddress = this.parseAddress(formData.address.address_components)

        const newState = {
          formData: {
            // Get formData from form submission
          }
        }

        const mergedState = {...this.state, ...newState}
        // Put formData in state
        this.setState(mergedState, () => {
          // Get API data
          getData(this.state.formData, (data) => {

            let newState = {
              data,
              loading: false
            }

            const mergedState = {...this.state, ...newState}

            this.setState(mergedState)
          })
        })
      }

      renderComponents = () => {
        if(isEmpty(this.state.formData) && this.state.data.medianScore === 0) {
          // Return Component
        } else {
          return <Report
                  loading={this.state.loading}
                  // A bunch more props.
                  />
        }
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.renderComponents()}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default App
```

from Report

```
    class Report extends React.Component {

      render () {

        const renderReport = () => {
          // This is where our problem is
          if (this.props.loading) {

            // These components render properly
          } else {
            // Even though this.props.loading gets set to false
            // These components never get renderd
          }
        }

        return (renderReport())
      }
    }

    export default Report
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: I need to see your code and before I can do some help.